# How could get scsi HDD serial number?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, scsi

I wanna get the serial number of a scsi harddisk, but it makes an error!
I work with VC++ on Microsoft Windows XP.

What must i do for that?

Comment: What programming environment are you using?  What operating system?  Can you post your code that gives an error, and the error output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here to find out how to query WMI using C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28VS.85%29.aspx

You'll need to look in `Win32_DiskDrive` for the disk and then retrieve the `SerialNumber` value.

Comment: I don't understand, could u explain more?
I am working with Windows API (DeviceIoControl).

Comment: Updated as above. I'm afraid I can't post any code samples as I don't program in C++.